# Dynamic id value for Struts 2 form

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I want to use a dynamic value for `id` attribute in Struts 2 form and other tags as well.

Below is the same code:

```jsp
<s:if test="null != #request.METHOD_CALL || #request.METHOD_CALL == 'ADD' ">
    <s:set name="pre" value="%{'a_'}" /> 
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set name="pre" value="%{'e_'}" /> 
</s:else>

<s:form action="saveMeetingAction" id="**<s:property value='pre'/>**_editForm">
<s:textfield  name = "recDt" id = "**<s:property value="pre"/>**rcrdDt" size='11' maxlength='11' />
```

I would like to see my form as below:

```jsp
<s:form action="saveMeetingAction" id="e_editForm">
<s:textfield  name = "recDt" id = "e_rcrdDt" size='11' maxlength='11' />

<s:form action="saveMeetingAction" id="a_editForm">
<s:textfield  name = "recDt" id = "a_rcrdDt" size='11' maxlength='11' />
```

Please suggest how to generate the id attribute in `<s:form>`. This is working fine with simple html form.

Comment: You cannot nest tags like that, in S2 tags use OGNL.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```jsp
<s:if test="null != #request.METHOD_CALL || #request.METHOD_CALL == 'ADD' ">
    <s:set var="pre" value="%{'a'}" /> 
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <s:set var="pre" value="%{'e'}" /> 
</s:else>

<s:form action="saveMeetingAction" id="%{#pre}_editForm">
<s:textfield  name = "recDt" id = "%{#pre}_rcrdDt" size='11' maxlength='11' />
```

If you are using Struts tag, you can make OGNL expression inside attributes. To define  a variable with the `set` tag you should use `var` attribute.